# How to position a JQueryUI datepicker dialog via a MouseEvent

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying launch a datepicker in dialog mode via clicking on some text.

```html
<input type='hidden' id='datepicker'>
<div onclick="getdate()">
    Click on me to launch DatePicker dialog
</div>
```

where

```js
function getdate() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("dialog", "10/12/2013", function(){alert("wibble");},{dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"},[20,20]);
}
```

Default dialog behaviour (no position) is fine (pops up centre screen), apart from Firefox which goes for top centre. Specifying position as Number[2] works fine as well.

The JQueryUI api documentation says:

> pos
>   Type: Number[2] or MouseEvent
>   The position of the top/left of the dialog as [x, y] or a MouseEvent that contains
>   the coordinates. If not specified the dialog is centered on the screen.

Unfortunately, they have no example of using a MouseEvent and I fear that I am reaching the limits of my ability in this area. I tried various formats such as:

```js
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("dialog", "10/12/2013", function(){alert("wibble");},{dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"},$.Event("mouseclick"));
```

to no avail. Googling for datapicker dialog method seems to bring up a plethora of websites happy to parrot the api documentation without expanding on it.

How does one pass in a MouseEvent to this method?

---

**Update**
Based on j08691's answer, this is the syntax that I was looking for:

```js
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(
    "dialog", 
    "10/12/2013", 
    function(){alert("wibble");},
    {dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"},
    event
);
```

---

**Update 2**

A bit more diddling on another computer with different versions of some browsers and a bit more research has led me to the following as my final answer:

```html
<input type='hidden' id='datepicker'>
<div onclick="getdate(event)">
    Click on me to launch DatePicker dialog
</div>
```

```js
function getdate(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(
        "dialog", 
        "10/12/2013", 
        function(date){changeDate(date);},
        {dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"},
        e
    );
}
```

(where changeDate is another function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the reason that there's not much on the web about this is that the only semi-useful, cross-browser [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) mouse properties that you would use are event.pageX and event.pageY.

For example:

```
function getdate() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("dialog", "10/12/2013", function () {
        alert("wibble");
    }, {
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    }, [event.pageX, event.pageY]);
}
```

See this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7w7tg/)** and click on the grey div. The datepicker will be placed at the coordinates of where the mouse clicks on the div.

Comment: Perfect. This was what I was looking for. In fact it's even more straightforward than that. `$("datepicker").datepicker("dialog","10/12/2013",function(){...},{dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"},event);` is enough. JQueryUI gets the coordinates for you. Of all the things I tried, I never thought that just "event" was enough. I guess it just represents the current event (which is of course onclick). Shows my javascript inexperience.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div onclick="getdate()">
    <input type='hidden' id='datepicker'>
    Click on me to launch DatePicker dialog
</div>
```

Comment: This didn't make any difference with the variations that I was trying. The problem was that I didn't know how to pass the event.